# Is the derivative of a continuous density function on $\mathbb{R}$ integrable?

Tags: probability, integration

Any continuous density function on $\mathbb{R}$ is integrable. Is it true that all derivatives of a probability density function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ is also integrable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a counter-example to your claim, i.e. a construction of a probability density whose derivative is not integrable.

Let $g$ be the following function $$
  g(x) = \begin{cases}
    0 &\text{if $x < 1$} \\
    2^{n-1} &\text{if $x \in [n,n+2^{-n})$} \\
    -2^{n-1} &\text{if $x \in [n+2^{-n},n+2^{-n+1}]$} \\
    0 &\text{otherwise,}
  \end{cases}
$$
i.e. $g$ takes the value $2^{n-1}$ the first $2^{-n}$ units after each integer, followed by the value $-2^{n-1}$, also for $2^{-n}$ units.

$g$ is obviously integrable over every compact interval, but not over the whole real line, since $$
  \int_{\mathbb{R}} g^+ = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g^- = \sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{n-1} 2^{-n} = \infty \text{.}
$$
Now set $$
  f(x) = \int_0^x g(t) \,dt = \begin{cases}
    0 &\text{if $x < 1$} \\
    \frac{1}{2} - 2^{n-1}|n + 2^{-n} - x| &\text{if $x \in [n,n+2^{-n+1}]$} \\
    0 &\text{otherwise.}
  \end{cases}
$$
Then $f \geq 0$ and $$
  \int_{[n,n+1]} f = \int_n^{n+2^{-n+1}} 1 - 2^n|n + 2^n - x|\,dx = 2^{-n} \text{,}
$$
therefore $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f = \sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-n} = 1$, and $f$ is thus a probability density.

Yet the derivative of $f$ - which is $g$ - is, as metioned, not integrable. I believe that the problem here is that $f$ is not absolutely continuous on the whole real line, but only on compact subsets, but I haven't been able to prove that your proposition holds if one requires $f$ to be AC on $\mathbb{R}$ yet. Note that $f$ not being absolutely continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't contradict that $f(x) = \int_0^x g(t) \,dt$, since absolute continuity on every *interval* suffices for that.

Another way to look at this is that if $f'$ was integrable, then $\int f' = \lim_{x\to\infty} \left(f(x) - f(-x)\right)$, but that limit doesn't exist here.

[image: plot of f and f']

Comment: yes we can have the derivative but how can I make sure that $\int_\mathbb{R} f^{'}(t)\mbox{d}t<\infty$ for all $f$?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören OK, I seem to have miss-understood your question. Here's a construction of a probability density with a non-integrable derivative.

Comment: is $f$ continuous everywhere in this example?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Yes! See the plot I just added.

Comment: thank you very much for the details. Yes I think for the case of absolute continuity perhaps the assertion holds. I have a very related problem, will be happy to hear your comments http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741606/integrability-of-ln-ly2-lyx-f-0y-on-real-numbers

Comment: @fgp Hi, after so many years, is the problem related to absolute continuity solved?